# Expo app deleted know unable to deploy new app on google play store

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play-console

I have created react native app using Expo and deployed it on the Google play store and it was live and working. Unfortunately, the expo app was deleted from my system.

I want to update my app with new features and bug fixes, so I created a new expo project how can I deploy it to the same app on the google play store?

Answer (score 0):

The project needs to have a higher version, as the existing one, same bundleID and you need to use the same upload key to upload the app to the play store